# Migrate from continuous aggregate to hierarchical aggregate in postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Currently, I have a set of continuous aggregates, which are as below:

> 5 mins
> 1 hour
> 1 day
> 1 week

I want to migrate them to hierarchical aggregates, such that data in the underlying hypertable is not lost. At present, I see an option to do as below:

> 1. Create a hierarchical aggregate with a new name.
> 2. Copy data from the old hypertable to the new hypertable.
> 3. Drop old aggregate.

However, I do see this as a cumbersome process. Is there a better way to handle this?